# The script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script

Tags: unity-game-engine

everybody. 
I'm beginner unity user.
When i study unity. my C# script file doesn't insert to prefabs.
And it return error message : The script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script.

this is my C# script code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class unPlayerMovement
{
    private Transform tr;

    public float moveSpeed = 30.0f;
    public float rotSpeed = 150.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;



tr = GetComponent<Transform>();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Move();
    }
    void Move(float h, float v)
    {
        tr.Rotate(0, v * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        tr.Translate(0, 0, h * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}



And this is my Unity screen.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLGJ3.png)

Answer (score 11):

Just had this issue too. Check the class name is the exact same as the file name, this fixed it for me.

In your case check the class `unPlayerMovement` is in a file called `unPlayerMovement.cs`

Answer (score 1):

This is how your whole script should look like. your Move() had an error too[Fixed]. that's probably the reason why unity was not loading the script. Let me know if you need any help :)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class unPlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

private Transform tr;

public float moveSpeed = 30.0f;
public float rotSpeed = 150.0f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
    tr = GetComponent<Transform>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Move(h,v);
}
void Move(float h, float v)
{
    tr.Rotate(0, v * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    tr.Translate(0, 0, h * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit from MonoBehaviour.

```
public class unPlayerMovement:MonoBehaviour
```

Comment: Doing so still causes the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you have counter error somewhere, you can see this error.
Firstly you should clear any error from console.

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting unPlayerMovement.cs.meta file ,

worked for me by deleting .cs.meta file