# Why is Unity throwing an error"The script dont inherit a native class that can manage" if class and file name are the same and inherit MonoBehaviour?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently started studying the book "Mobile Game Development with Unity" by John Manning and there was a problem with the code.

Unity keeps throwing this error when trying to add a component.
**"The script dont inherit a native class that can manage"**

Here is the code itself. The name of the class and the code are the same. I've been digging the Internet for several hours and just can't find a solution.

The code was attached to the book and it also gives an error when added.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent (typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class BodyPart: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite detachedSprite;
    public Sprite burnedSprite;
    public Transform bloodFountainOrigin;
    bool detached = false;
    public void Detach()
    {
        detached = true;
        this.tag = "Untagged";
        transform.SetParent(null, true);
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (detached == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        var rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rigidbody.IsSleeping())
        {
            foreach (Joint2D joint in GetComponentsInChildren<Joint2D>())
            {
                Destroy(joint);
            }
            foreach (Rigidbody2D body in GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody2D>())
            {
                Destroy(body);
            }
            foreach (Collider2D collider in GetComponentsInChildren<Collider2D>())
            {
                Destroy(collider);
            }
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
    public void ApplyDamageSprite(Gnome.DamageType damageType)
    {
        Sprite spriteToUse = null;
        switch (damageType)
        {
            case Gnome.DamageType.Burning:
                spriteToUse = burnedSprite;
                break;
            case Gnome.DamageType.Slicing:
                spriteToUse = detachedSprite;
                break;
        }
        if (spriteToUse != null)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spriteToUse;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the file the same name as the class, `BodyPart`? Try matching the fileName to BodyPart.cs

Comment: @rustyBucketBay 
I did this in the first place, but unfortunately there is no error in this :с

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of other forum posts on this error including [a Unity community post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/the-script-dont-inherit-a-native-class-that-can-manage-a-script.1011988/), [a Unity Answers post,](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1742343/the-script-dont-inherit-a-native-class-that-can-ma.html) and [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62399946/the-script-dont-inherit-a-native-class-that-can-manage-a-script)

Most of them concur that it is an issue with Unity, not the script itself. I would recommend starting with the suggestions in these posts

1. Restart Unity
2. If you added the script while running the game, stop and recompile
3. Confirm that the script name matches exactly
4. Remove any spaces from script name
5. Update to the latest release of your version of Unity
6. Reinstall Unity

If you've tried any of these already, please let us know what you've done to fix the problem and we can try to assist more

Comment: Unfortunately none of this helped. It looks like it's just a bug. Or you need an earlier version of Unity